# Js magic need explanation

Tags: javascript, post-increment, pre-increment

I'm trying to solve this magic in js:

```
var a = 1;
console.log(a++ + ++a);
```

It returns 4 and I can understand that it's 1+3 but what is the sequence of this?

Comment: If you understand what post-increment and pre-increment operators do, it becomes pretty obvious. You just need to read the docs and the knowledge that code is executed from left to right.

Comment: I do yet it doesn't seem obvious. Can you just describe it like 1)... 2)... 3)... in your answer?

Comment: @Jonasw What does `2 + 2` have to do with that?

Comment: If you see code like this in real life, then it was written by a horrible person.  There are good reasons to use `++a` or `a++` depending on the scenario, but having 5 plus signs in a row for any reason is a bad idea for readability, and is just asking for a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a++` means return the value before incrementing

`++a` means returns the value after incrementing

So to break down your example:

```
var a = 1;
console.log(a++ + ++a);
```

1. `a` is set to `1`
2. `a++` returns 1, and then `a` is incremented to `2` (but we don't do anything with it at this point)
3. `++a` increments `a` and returns 3
4. Then altogether we have `console.log(1 + 3)` with the `1` coming from step 1 and the `3` coming from step 3.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the sequence of this

In pseudo spec language:

1. Evaluate addition (`a++ + ++a`)

   1. Let `lval` be the result of evaluating the left operand (`a++`)

      1. Get the value of `a` and assign it to `oldValue`. (`1`)
      2. Let `newValue` be `oldValue + 1`.
      3. Assign `newValue` to `a`. (`a == 2`)
      4. Return `oldValue`. (`1`)
   2. Let `rval` be the result of evaluating the right operand (`++a`)

      1. Get the value of `a` and assign it to  `oldValue`. (`2`)
      2. Let `newValue` be `oldValue + 1`.
      3. Assign `newValue` to `a`. (`a == 3`)
      4. Return `newValue`. (`3`)
   3. Return `lval + rval`. (`1 + 3`)
2. Result: `4`

Answer (score 1):

To go into a bit more detail on what [Xufox was saying in the comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710867/js-magic-need-explanation/39710951#comment66719653_39710867):

`++a` first increments the value of a and then returns an lvalue referring to a, so if the value of a is used then it will be the incremented value.

`a++` first returns an rvalue whose value is a, that is, the old value, and then increments a at an unspecified time before the next full-expression (i.e., "before the semicolon").

Postfix increment has higher precedence than prefix increment.

This helped me a lot back in the day and it should help you too..

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec